# Can't run Doggcatcher and Endomondo simultaneously

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, ram, processes, huawei-u8860

I'd like to listen to music with Doggcatcher and record the routes with Endomondo while bicycling. The problem is, when I start Endomondo, after a couple of minutes Android kills Doggcatcher. When I start Doggcatcher, after a couple of minutes Android kills Endomondo. What can I do? I'd rather kill any other application or service than these two, but I've already tried uninstalling almost every other app except the system apps. I have stock Android ICS and Huawei Honor.

Comment: Rather than editing your solution into your question, you should create a new answer with that information and then _accept_ it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question from what I've gathered. There seems to be no way to prioritize, say, Doggcatcher, if it's playing music in the background. When the operating system runs out of memory, it starts summarily killing background processes. The best I can do is kill dispensable background processes before starting these two apps.

First I turn off sync. Then I go to *Manage apps* and open the *Running* tab, note which apps are running, open the *Downloaded* tab, and from there *Force stop* the apps. Note that if you simply stop the services from the *Running* tab, the apps will usually restart them. After that I clear the app cache from the *All* tab. I'm not sure how necessary this step is, as the problem occurs rather nondeterministically. After that I start Doggcatcher and Endomondo.

Especially Facebook app just keeps starting all kinds of services that consume a lot of memory, no matter how it's configured, so I uninstalled the app and started using the mobile site with web browser. The mobile site is also more robust, I think it has more features, and I got rid of the annoying notifications.

Comment: You're right that when memory is tight, Android starts killing background services; but if it shows an "ongoing" notification then Doggcatcher is running as a *foreground* service. This ensures that Android won't kill it until there are no background services left.

Comment: Now that you mention, I don't think Doggcatcher shows the playback controls in the notification area anymore. I don't know if that's the problem, but surely Android kills Doggcatcher while Facebook and other apps still have a bunch of background services running.

Comment: If it doesn't, then that's a bug in Doggcatcher, and you should report it to the author. Its screenshots on Google Play show a notification icon.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Turned out Doggcatcher should show a notification icon when playing music in the background with the intention of keeping it alive. Usually it doesn't, but changing the preference Settings > Advanced > Keep Alive to Always will make the notification icon stay there. (Now the icon shows even when Doggcatcher is not playing music, but it doesn't matter since one can exit the application to release the memory it's reserving.)